# Jenkins Clone/Checkout Git Repository of Upstream Job

Tags: git, bash, powershell, github, jenkins

### Problem

I am working on a factory Job in Jenkins and came to the idea of checking out, or cloning, a Git Repository based that the Upstream Job has checked out.

```
EX: Job A uses Git Repo 1
    Job B uses Git Repo 2
    Job C uses Git Repo 3
    Job D is the Factory Job

    Job D is called by Jobs A - C upon successful build

    If Job A calls Job D, Job D clones/checks out Repo 1 and performs its tasks using that Repo
    If Job B calls Job D, Job D clones/checks out Repo 2 and performs its tasks using that Repo
    If Job C calls Job D, Job D clones/checks out Repo 3 and performs its tasks using that Repo
```

I have been searching for how to do this, if it is possible, for a few hours now... The closest thing I found was 'How to load multiple repositories into a single job'. This isn't quite what I want to do, especially as it could cause the Job to continously grow as more repositories are added in time. This doesn't seem properly scaleable to me.

### Question

In Jenkins, is there a reasonably scaleable way for a downstream Job to clone/checkout the same Git Repository an upstream Job is using when it triggers the downstream job?

Answer (score 1):

Define your job D with a parameter like git_url, and use this variable in your git repository url, then use the Parameterized Trigger Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) for calling it from any upstream job.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin can be used to trigger parameterized build as post-build action passing parameters downstream. So if You set the Factory job to be parameterized, it can use parameters of the upstream job.

A solution would look like this:

```
EX: Job A uses Git Repo 1
    Job B uses Git Repo 2
    Job C uses Git Repo 3
    Job D is the Factory Job parameterized with P

    Jobs A - C triggers D as parameterized build
        with predefined parameter P upon successful build
        let P be Repo 1 - 3 according to Job A - C

    If Job A calls Job D, Job D clones/checks out P and performs its tasks using that Repo
    If Job B calls Job D, Job D clones/checks out P and performs its tasks using that Repo
    If Job C calls Job D, Job D clones/checks out P and performs its tasks using that Repo
```